# on button click i have fetch (list) the data with help of ajax now i want to insert(submit) this data into another table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After submiting the form i am not getting the post data on page.
This is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>employee list</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="fetch" >
<option value='emp_id'>multiple names of employee </option>
</select>
<form method="post" action="addempaonthertbl.php">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Batch no</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="listing">
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

script runs after changing the drop down

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("fetch").change(function()
{
$.ajax({
type: 'POST', 
data: 'emp_id='+emp_id,     
url: 'fetch.php' ,
success: function(response)
{
jQuery('#listing').html(response);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

All the fetch details of employee from fetch.php

```
$result = $this->db->query(" select * from tbl_emp where emp_id ='$emp_id'")->result_array();
$x = 1;
foreach($result as $row)
{
$pid = $row['prodid'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $x++. "</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['name']. "</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['batchno']. "</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['address']. "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

I have added some code and modify some part but the post still cannot be submitted.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Try to add a form outside that foreach. Like: `<form><?php foreach($result as $row){ ... } ?></form>`, and then get the data from this new form and save it to the desired db table.

Comment: not working sir. form is not submitting

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Select name in Javascript like you use. you can use id in Select option than use that id in javascript.

**Try this Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>employee list</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <select name="fetch" id="fetch">
         <option value='emp_id'>multiple names of employee </option>
      </select>
      <form method="post" action="addempaonthertbl.php">
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Batch no</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="listing"></tbody>
         </table>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fetch").change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'emp_id=' + emp_id,
                url: 'fetch.php',
                success: function(response) {
                    jQuery('#listing').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i want to know how i can submit the data to another page which is fetch from ajax. i already have fetch the result just i want to submit it to another page.

Comment: I dint get you .... On which action you want to do post data. like on select, on click button.

Comment: on click buttton sir

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are in the same folder as `fetch.php`, otherwise it will send the POST to an invalid location. You have a problem with your selector as well. Change

```
$("fetch").change(function()
```

to

```
$("select[name=fetch]").change(function()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can insert each `foreach` loop in the table, directly in the loop. For example, if you are using `pdo`:

```
$db = new PDO('...');
foreach($result as $row){ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl SET name=?,batchno=?,address=?'); 
    $stmt->execute([$row['name'], $row['batchno'], $row['address']]);
    //...
}
```